# How to get String from weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Clob_oracle_sql_CLOB?

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, clob

**Environment**: Oracle 11g, Weblogic 9.2, Java 4, driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

**Context:** I want to extract an xml value from a database and work with the result in Java, using the following select:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(XML_TEXT, 'PATH/TO/XML/VALUE/text()').getClobVal() AS VALUE 
FROM MYTBALE WHERE id =xxxx;
```

**Problem**: In the SQL Developer, I do can see the string retreived fine, but in Java:

- If I use the `getClobVal()` function Weblogic returns a wrapped object of type `weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Clob_oracle_sql_CLOB` which I'm not able to cast or unwrap.
- If I don't use `getClobVal()` returns an `oracle.sql.Opaque`, which I'm not able to cast to anything either.

**Code**:
  Using `getClobVal()`:

```
...
HashMap <String, Object> element = (HashMap) iter.next();
String value = (unwrap & cast in some way ) element.get("VALUE");
...
```

I can't find a way to get the string from that object, any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I can't disable Weblogic wrapping. I'm thinking in making some workaround in database side to get a blob instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I could not unwrap or cast the object, I ended up working in the database it self:

```
create or replace procedure MANAGE_DOCUMENT(
  pSomeParam IN someTable.someColumn%TYPE,#if we need some param.
  pError OUT VARCHAR2
  )IS
  vResult BLOB;
  vDoc CLOB;

  begin
    pError := '';

    #extract base64 document
    SELECT EXTRACT(myColumn, 'xPath/to/the/element/text()').getClobVal()
    into vDoc
    FROM myTable WHERE someCondition;

    #check if doc exists
    IF vDoc IS NULL THEN
      pError :='Document not found';
    ELSE
      #decode and get blob
      vResult := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(vDoc);
      #do inserts or whatever        
      END IF;
    END IF; 
end MANAGE_DOCUMENT;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your WebLogic console disable the wrapping of data types (under `Connection Pool` -> `Advanced`, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/jdbc/jdbc_datasources/DisableWrapping.html)). Restart the server and now you will get a `oracle.sql.CLOB` object instead of a `weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Clob_oracle_sql_CLOB` one.

**EDIT**: For that specific method/class, you can use the specific vendor connection (`getVendorConnection()` [method](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24376/phys_conr.htm#JDBCP1037)) which should return unwrapped objects.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I forgot to point I cannot disable that option because is already configured in production server. The code is prepared to handle determinate castings, but not this one.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer with a possible workaround.